# ajax success print multiple data

Tags: ajax

i am new in this ajax . i got a problem that is in my ajax  coding i get a multiple data in loop so how can print that multiple data in ajax success 
here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxdate',
    data: {ending:ending},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {

    $('#info1').text(data);
    console.log(data.length);
    alert(data);

       /*for(var item in data){
      console.info(item);//print key
          console.info(data[item]);//print value
    }*/
    }
});

function ajaxdate()
```

{
       $data=array();

```
   foreach ($guestbookdetail as $guestbookdetail)
   {
    echo $data['full_name'] = $detail['list']['full_name']."\n";
    }           
}
```

How i print that multiple data in ajax success

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with is expect JSON as response.
I see the problem in your function if you are printing the full_name in loop and expecting HTML response, all it will be just a string.

What you can do is something like this

```
 function ajaxdate()
 { 
     $data=array();

     foreach ($guestbookdetail as $guestbookdetail)
     {
          $data[]['full_name'] = $detail['list']['full_name'];
     } 
     die(json_encode($data));          
 }
```

This will return a json array with collection of object of full_name eg [{full_name: 'ABC'},{full_name: 'cde'}]

Then add dataType : 'json' in you ajax.

Now you can iterate thorough the response you get in ajax success.

Comment: first i thank you to give me replay friend i do as u say but still result is nothing

Comment: Can you share what you are getting in response of ajax call and then how are you iterating through the response, Please share the code

Comment: this is in reponse in fire bug -> [{"full_name":"Raj chuhan"},{"full_name":"Dixita Dave"}]...and for iterating i wrote above code is same i just remove the comment friend

Comment: $.each(data, function(key, detail) {
          console.log(detail.full_name);
      });

This will console Raj Chuhan and Dixita Dave.

Answer (score 0):

For an example you have this `<ul id="showResultHere"></ul>` tag, where you would like to show the result, then TRY this in your "success" AJAX :

```
success: function (data){
     $.each(data, function(index) {
          //alert(data[index]);
          $("#showResultHere").append("<li>" + data[index] + "</li>");
     });
}
```

Or, another way to show your "full_name" from your guestbook array, here is another option too :

```
success: function (data){
     data.forEach(function(data) {
          $("#showResultHere").append("<li>" + data + "</li>");
     });
}
```